# How to include/install other font types

Tags: fonts

How would you include/install other font types such as ComicSans (and others) which are resident in Mozilla ThunderBird Email when used in Windows O/S, but not resident in Mozilla ThunderBird Email in the Ubuntu O/S?

Thanks,
michael m.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your fonts folder from Windows to Ubuntu (You can put it anywhere on your Ubuntu machine), and install Fonty Python from the USC, and then it's as simple as making Pogs of the fonts you want to use.  You just pick the font through Fonty Python, add it to a Pog, and install it.  Simple as that.  Then just choose the font/s you want in what programs you want like normal.  The new fonts will show with the defaults.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/fontypython/

Comment: Thanks Bobby...I will try that. But tell me, what is/are Pog(s)?

Comment: Pogs are the individual "sets" of fonts you can have.  You don't have to install all fonts at once.  Say you want Arial, Arial Condensed, and Arial Bold.  You can install them all together, or one by one via Pogs.  Think of them as separate folder of each font if you will.  Once you have them set up you can install or uninstall at will.  All you have to do is click on a Pog to install, uninstall, or delete.  It's very easy to use once you start.